# How to catch error and print to user

Tags: php, laravel, render

I'm trying to print the errors that usually come in the gray screen , but capturing them in a html and displaying the user to use the system.
For this I am using the render method and a view on the resources / views / errors / error.php folder and I'm doing the following:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
 {
   return response()->view('errors.error', [], 500);
 }
```

This effectively is showing me what I have in error.php html file but want to show the user the actual error captured.

As I do ? Help !!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to think if you really want to show the user the error detail. (Probably not). In fact, the detail you see in the "gray screen" varies according to the value of `APP_DEBUG` in your `.env` file.

Typically you want to hide from users the reason behind the failing, and display a very generic error message. For HTTP exceptions, the exception handler will do it for you: just create a blade file for each http code you want to handle (`resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` for instance).

If you want this for debugging purposes, there are better tools. Checking the error log is the most basic one. Or use the `dd()` function here and there to look at the state of some variable at any point.

If you really really want to do this, you can modify the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`file, `render` method as you suggest

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
   return response()->view('errors.error', [
       'error_message' => $e->getMessage()
   ], $code);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand perfectly, but that would not otherwise redirected the user to the page where you get the error ?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand that. The `render` function I wrote there just renders the 'error' view, passing in the message of the exception so you can display it any way you like.